# Continuous Mapping Theorem in infinite dimension

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, convergence

We have from the Continuous Mapping Theorem (CMT) that for $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ a sequence of random variables $X_n:\Omega \to  \mathbb R^p, \forall n \in \mathbb N$ and a continuous function $g: \mathbb R^p \to \mathbb R^d$ with both $p,d<\infty$. If there exists a random variable $X$ such that $X_n \overset{p}{\rightarrow}X$, then $g(X_n) \overset{p}{\rightarrow} g(X)$.

I want to know if there exists some version of the CMT with at least $d=\infty$. Does any one know some reference for this?